# How do I get one jquery datepicker input to integrate with value of another?

Tags: jquery, calendar, datepicker

I have a form with 3 input fields that use jQuery's DatePicker plugin.  The fields are #startdate, #enddate, and #raindate.  I am using DatePicker's event function to get the #startdate and #enddate to work together so the #enddate cannot be before the #startdate. Both those fields are required, by the way.  The #raindate field is not required. However, if the user wants to add a date here, I want it to be after the date selected in the #enddate.  How do I do this?  Here is the code I have for getting the startdate and enddate to work together:

```
function getDates() {
    var dates = $("#startdate, #enddate" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1d",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "startdate" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" );
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                   instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                   $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                   selectedDate, instance.settings );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to specify something like this?:

```
minDate: $(#enddate).val() + 1d
```

Comment: You may want to look at the Filament Group's [date range picker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an option called minDate and it also supports a lot more options.

To get all available options go to -

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Over there go to options tab.

The above can be achieved by following code -

```
  $('#raindate').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd M yy",
    beforeShow: customRange,
    //Your other configurations.
    });

  function customRange(input) {
   if (input.id == "raindate")
    {
    dateMin = new Date();
    if ($("#enddate").datepicker("getDate") != null)
    {
    dateMin = $("#enddate").datepicker("getDate");
    dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + 1); 
    }
    }
    return {
    minDate: dateMin
  }; 
}​
```

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in my question.  I have my #startdate and #enddate working correctly using the example above.  However, I want the #raindate to have a minDate that is 1 day beyond that of the #enddate that is selected.

Comment: I have modified my code as per your requirements. Hope it helps you out :)

Comment: just tried it. The calendar for #raindate doesn't hide any dates before the #enddate.

Comment: At the beginning of this code just insert this line. $('#raindate').datepicker( "destroy" ); and try.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't prevent the raindate from showing all dates either.